# Screen Readers not reading numbers as individual digits

Tags: javascript, css, screen-readers

I tried finding answer but no luck. Solutions provided across web is not satisfactory. Is there any way in Javascript, HTML or CSS to make screen reader to read numbers individually?

It's reading fine if I put a zero before.

```
<span>Account #: 0123</span> // Reading correct as 'Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three'

<span>Account #: 123</span> // Reading wrong as 'One hundred twenty three'
```

Comment: is it a system screen reader?

Comment: Yes John, it's NVDA. But it could be others too.

Comment: possibly worth revisiting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092024/3022387

Comment: it's definitely harder to directly to communicate with a system screen reader. couldn't a hacky solution be to insert spaces between the numbers and then "remove" those spaces with css

Comment: @flowtron, it was not resolved there.

Comment: @JohnKrakov, okay, if there is no other ways then :)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Please don't do anything.

If you absolutely want to force single-digit reading, you may use `aria-label` on your span, but actually, please don't do it if there is no absolute and unavoidable need to.
The main thing about screen readers is that they convey the *same* information as your monitor to your eyes. The key notion here is *the same*, i.e., doing something that would unnecessarily differ from what you see on your monitor is bad in 99.(9)% of cases. I said "unnecessarily" because sometimes it's good to convey additional info: for example, add `aria-pressed` to a toggle button to mark whether it is pressed or unpressed (which can easily be seen visually with appropriate CSS in place).
If you believe that your digits are too difficult to perceive and need to be separated, first try to separate them with spaces and look whether it's visually appealing or not. My feeling is that you will be somewhat irritated to see `Account number: 0 1 2 3` instead of the plain `0123`. If it's the case, then believe me, a blind user will be irritated too. If it's OK for you, then go for such a solution, style it appropriately, use non-breaking spaces, but don't do anything special for screen readers in this case.